# Decision problem 3SAT and Bip[3-1]

Tags: graphs, np-hard, decision-problem, 3-sat

Consider the decision problem Bip[3–1], define as follows:

- Instance: $G = (S,T;E)$, bipartite graph, with $d_G(s) = 3$ for all $s \in S$.
- Question: Does there exist $S' ⊆ S$ such that in $H = [S'∪T]_G$ we have $d_H(t) = 1$ for all $t \in T$?

I should prove that 3SAT reduces to Bip[3-1].

I understand what the problem says, but I don't know how such relations could be proved, and neither have I found any decision problems similar to this.

Would appreciate any help.